# Getting approximate location without using GPS (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, maps, location, geocoding

is there a way to find out the location without using GPS on the Windows phone 7. It's okay if ts approximate, as i want to get the city (not the precise longitude and latitude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the location API within Windows Phone 7 is described in [this collection of MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Pay special attention to the section in [Location Programming: Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431814%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) about the right level of accuracy. When setting the GeoCoordinateWatcher to default instead of high accuracy it is optimzed for power-usage. In practice this means it will only resort to GPS of there is nothing else available.

All use of the location API will require you to ask the user for permission to use their location. The only way to get around that (if you really want to) is by using one of the tricks described in other answers.

Comment: yea, i just read that from this blog [link](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/25/using-the-location-service-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone.aspx) its not as fast as the app i saw but it gave me faster response. i think theres no other solution, but thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not allowed by their policy. You have to use their Location services and include a on/off switch as well as privacy policy.

If you'll try to work around that, it may not pass the certification.

Comment: but i've seen some apps getting my location without GPS, i know that coz i am indoor and when i try to run my app (which uses GPS) it wont get the location, unlike other apps, they get the location right away.
one of the apps is "salatok"

Comment: it may be storing your location from the last access, and displaying it. why won't you just use location service?

Comment: no, it doesnt do that, i have two phones, so i tried to install it again on the other device, and it got it right away. i just want to see if its possible, coz it would be better if i can find it through the ip address or something

Comment: The phone does store its latest location.  I'm sure that's what you're getting.

Comment: how can i get that stored location value?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find out the IP address assigned by an ISP (such as the IP address of the wireless router you connect to or the phone itself if it is on 4G (?)), you can use a GeoIP look-up. demo: http://www.geoiptool.com/